What is the meaning of the namespace in Harbor replication rule
What is the meaning of the namespace during the creation of Harbor replication rule.
I have seen this: (https://goharbor.io/docs/2.0.0/administration/configuring-replication/create-replication-rules/), but it does not really answer my question.
How can I check namespace?
Thanks in advance,
Michal.
Currently during run of replication I see error:
{     "errors": [         {             "code": "NOT_FOUND",             "message": "{\"code\":10010,\"message\":\"object is not found\",\"details\":\"b585659c082d58ddadf5f9a7\"}"         }     ] }
I am expecting that this is related to namespace missing.

I found out that Namespace in replication means project name.
